# GWT widget being truncated on Panel

Tags: image, gwt

I have the following class which adds an image to a button and then adds the button to a panel

```
private PushButton button;
private AbsolutePanel panel = new AbsolutePanel();
private Image image = new Image("images/rectangle_blue.png");

public ExpandingRectangularButton(String text)
{
    String width = "120px";
    String height = "160px";
    image.setWidth(width);
    image.setHeight(height);
    button = new PushButton(image);
    panel.add(button, 0, 0);
    panel.setWidth(width);
    panel.setHeight(height);
    initWidget( panel );
}
```

When I display an instance of ExpandingRectangularButton the button is truncated on the bottom.  However if I take the panel out of the equation as follows

```
private PushButton button;
private Image image = new Image("images/rectangle_blue.png");

public ExpandingRectangularButton(String text)
{
    String width = "120px";
    String height = "160px";
    image.setWidth(width);
    image.setHeight(height);
    button = new PushButton(image);
    initWidget( button );
}
```

and just use the image and the button ( ie I call init() on the button ) then the image will display with no truncation.  As I don't set the height of the button I assume it grows dynamically to accomodate it's child widget.  Why does this not happen when I put the button onto the panel?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the Javadoc:

> An absolute panel positions all of its children absolutely, allowing them to overlap.
>
> Note that this panel will not automatically resize itself to allow enough room for its absolutely-positioned children. It must be explicitly sized in order to make room for them.

You can:

- explicitly set the `AbsolutePanel` size;
- remove the `overflow: hidden` property from it (workaround);
- use `panel.add(button, -1, -1)` to position the button statically;
- change the `AbsolutePanel` with one that naturally adapt its size (like almost any other `Panel`).

I'd prefer the last, but your use case is not clear.

Comment: I forgot to add to the OP that I had tried explicitly setting the Panel size to the same as the child. As per the docs ( Updated now ) but this made no difference.  I need to use an Absolute panel because I can find no other way to dynamically position a label depending on it's text length on top of a button with a background image